# Java project to .jar/.exe

Tags: java, ms-access, jar, exe, netbeans-7

I created a Java project using Netbeans IDE 7.4. The project is connected to MS Access driver for saving and retrieving project data from MS Access database. When I tried to make the .jar file to .exe file, it showed me an error message saying that "the data source is not available  the exe doesn't contain the DB!!".
Any idea how to solve this?

I tried many conversion way such build and clean, cvf command and I tried to use an external tool called exe4j, but all shows me the same error - the problem is that the database driver doesn't bulged with the .jar or .exe file. It's like if it's not part of the project!
It just work on the machine where I made the project. The error appears when I install my .jar on other machines.

Comment: This question needs more info on what your conversion process you used was, and if you know where that error message came from.

Comment: Just added that in the question

Comment: So are you getting this error from the exe4j tool, or did you successfully create an exe, but then while running it on other computers you get the error message? There's probably a lot more details that you can add that will probably be needed for this question, like what have you tried so far, what kind of database, is it stored in the jar, how do you communicate to it, what you have tried so far, that sort of thing.

Comment: These type of problems usually arise when you don't package the external data correctly in the jar file. I don't use Netbeans, but you should have an option ao add external resources which will be packed in the jar.

Comment: Does it work correctly when you run from the jar, rather than converting to an exe?

Comment: The error not from exe4j its come while running on other machines. I try exe4j and regular build and clean also cvf command,I used MS Access database and I create DSN driver for the DB and I manipulate the database through the driver using  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

Comment: Actually I don't know anything about package external data!! How can I do such thing!!

Comment: No its run correctly just within the netbeans. Otherwise its side there's no data source with both .jar and .exe version.